# Is IFS a shell-builtin, an Environment variable, or something else, by definition?

Tags: terminology

In Bourne shell and derivates,

Is IFS a shell-builtin, an Environment variable, or something else, by definition?
(How is this program module normally categorized in the literature?)

Answer (score 1):

According to this source,
[2. Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05):

> 2.5.3 Shell Variables
>
> Variables shall be initialized from the environment (as defined by XBD
> Environment Variables and the exec function in the System Interfaces
> volume of POSIX.1-2017) and can be given new values with variable
> assignment commands. If a variable is initialized from the
> environment, it shall be marked for export immediately; see the export
> special built-in. New variables can be defined and initialized with
> variable assignments, with the read or getopts utilities, with the
> name parameter in a for loop, with the ${ name= word} expansion, or
> with other mechanisms provided as implementation extensions.

And specifically `IFS`:

> IFS
> A string treated as a list of characters that is used for field splitting, expansion of the `*` special parameter, and to split lines
> into fields with the read utility. If the value of `IFS` includes any
> bytes that do not form part of a valid character, the results of field
> splitting, expansion of `*`, and use of the `read` utility are
> unspecified.
>
> If `IFS` is not set, it shall behave as normal for an unset variable, except that field splitting by the shell and line splitting
> by the `read` utility shall be performed as if the value of `IFS` is
> `<space> <tab> <newline>`; see Field Splitting.
>
> The shell shall set `IFS` to `<space> <tab> <newline>` when it is invoked.